# Grouping data in R data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

What is sql group by equivalent of R 
For example 
I want perform this on a data.frame

```
SELECT MAX(temp) from table group by day
```

by subset function
Note::

> I know about sqldf and I don't want use it for some purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can either use `aggregate` from `base R`.  Here, I am using the formula method, where the grouping variable is on the RHS of the `~`.  Specify the `FUN` as `max` to get the maximum value of 'temp'

```
aggregate(temp~day, df1, FUN = max)
```

Or using `dplyr`, we group by 'day' and get the `max` of temp within `summarise`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(day) %>%
    summarise(temp= max(temp))
```

Or using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'day', we get the `max` of 'temp'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(temp=max(temp)), by = day]
```

Comment: in the first function how can I select max(temp)?

Comment: @Goutam It is the formula method of aggregate.  The variable on the RHS of `~` is the grouping variable.  We specify the FUN as `max` which gets the max value of `temp` variable.

Comment: I want to do something like this `setDT(df1)[, list(temp=max(temp)), by = format(day,"%Y-%m-%d")]`

Comment: @Goutam The code in your post didn't show the `format`.  By the way, if the `day` is a `Date` object, the `format` should work.  It is not easy to guess when you don't show any data.

Comment: That is the first level question and this is the next level question?

Comment: @Goutam If the `day` is not a 'Date' class, then convert to `Date` using `as.Date(day, format='....')` and use that as grouping variable.

Comment: The Day is date class with time I want return max temp of the day

Comment: @Goutam Then, it would be `POSIXct` or `POSIXlt` class.  `format` should work on that.

Comment: It says something like this 
`Error in format.default(structure(as.character(x), names = names(x), dim = dim(x),  :
  invalid 'trim' argument`

Comment: @Goutam Can you update your post with few lines of example, i.e. `dput(droplevels(head(yourdata)))`

Comment: Thanks.solved it by `aggregate(temp~format(as.Date(day),"%Y-%m-%d"), df1, FUN = max)`

Comment: @Goutam Glad to know that it solved.  Perhaps even `as.Date(day)` should work?

Comment: Sorry for digging out an old question.
With `base R`, maybe it's also worth mentioning `tapply`, e.g. `tapply(df1$temp, df1$day, max)`.